# Использование JS обработчиков для тэга <tr> в <table>

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!
Необходимо на всю строку таблицы повесить обработчики событий. Т.е. на события mouseover, click,mouseout для каждой строки в таблице вешается свой обработчик. (Независимо от того, на какую ячейку навел мышку/кликнул пользователь, срабатывает общий алгоритм).

Т.к. табличка строится динамически через JS добавил следующий код при формировании:

```
ttable=document.createElement('table');
row = ttable.insertRow(-1);
row.setAttribute('mouseover','set_order_mouseover(this)');
row.setAttribute('click','set_order_mouseover(this)');
row.setAttribute('mouseout','set_order_mouseover(this)');
...код формирования ячеек
```

Функция set_order_mouseover:

```
function set_order_mouseover(el){
    alert('1');
}
```

В результате отработки JS строится таблица со следующим HTML кодом:

```
<table class="uk-table" id="history_table">
<tbody>
<tr mouseover="set_order_mouseover(this)" click="set_order_mouseover(this)" mouseout="set_order_mouseover(this)" >
<td>1</td>
<td>2017.03.20 14:02</td>
<td>НФ-00000000025</td>
<td>Москва г, Квесисская 2-я ул, 18</td>
<td>105120, Москва г, Сыромятнический 3-й пер, 3/9 стр. 1</td>
<td>420</td>
<td>Отменен</td><td>2017.03.21 15:00</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Но ни одно из событий не срабатывает. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильный вызов событий:
click="set_order_mouseover(this)" меняем на `onclick="set_order_mouseover(this)"`, а mouseout="set_order_mouseover(this) на `onmouseout="set_order_mouseover(this)"`.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло